# Summary of recent events web part

Tags: 2007, aggregation

How can I acumulate recent changes on one single start page. I want to see latest changes
as a single stream, with things coming from various lists like news, forums, document libraries etc etc
and I want to show it on a "Recent Events/ Recent Changes" webpart.

It is moss 2007 (but we are moving into 2010 ASAP).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog post I wrote about aggregating content in 2010.  Most of it also applies to 2007 though.  http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/04/content-aggregation-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Normally you look to roll up specific types of content like announcements or events.  For content changes you may need to use the Search API to bring back entries based on their modification date.